# How to flatten a 3 dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I use Pyaudio to record multichannel signal (2 for example) by appending each 2-dimensional list together. Now I would like to find an efficient way to flatten the signal to one single 2 dimensional array:

For example, input is :

```
i = [[[ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  2]], 
     [[ 3,  4],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 3,  4]]
    ]
i = np.array(i)
```

this `i` has a shape of `(2,3,2)`, and I would like to flatten it to shape of (2x3, 2)

```
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4]])
```

Any suggestion? Many thanks

Comment: Simply reshape to that desired shape?

Comment: `np.concatenate(i, 0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.concatenate`:

```
print(np.concatenate(i, 0))
```

Output:

```
 [[1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]
 [3 4]
 [3 4]
 [3 4]]
```

Comment: I do several 1000x timeit between np.concatenate and np.reshape and found concat to be consistently faster. Thanks. About 150us for concat and 200us for reshape with a (130000, 2) size data (about 3 seconds of audio at 44.1kHz).

Answer (score 1):

It should work :

```
i.reshape(2*3, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.. I gave the answer to np.concatenate because it is faster than reshape.

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
[item for sublist in i for item in sublist]
```

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4]]
```